# XAML: How to define dictionary value from resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I have defined IntMaping Dictionary in xaml resources like this:

```
<conv:IntToTextParam.IntMaping >
<System:String x:Key="0">SomeText not from App.Resources</System:String>
</conv:IntToTextParam.IntMaping>
```

where IntMapping is defined as Dictionary(string,string). I need define text value as string from app resource dictionary. Something like this:

```
<conv:IntToTextParam.IntMaping >
<System:String x:Key="0">{x:Static res:Resources.SomeText}</System:String>
</conv:IntToTextParam.IntMaping>
```

where res is xmlns:res ="clr-namespace:App.UI.Properties". But I dont know how to do it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Xaml ResourceDictionary already is a, well, dictionary. Why do you want to put another dictionary in it?

Comment: IntMaping is used in converter as parameter. It maps numbers to text. Text has to be localizable and therefore is defined in App.UI.Properties. Than Im able create resources for each language.